# QML: best performance timer for ShaderEffects

Tags: performance, qt, glsl, qml, shader

I need push to pixel shader the time incremented property for animation, with name '*iGlobalTime*'. Where
'*iGlobalTime*' - **shader playback time (in seconds)**.

But not something looped like:

```
UniformAnimator on iGlobalTime { from: 0; to: Math.PI * 2; duration: 1000 }
```

While I need always increment value.

I found two solutions, but I think for shaders this methods not have best perphomance:

**1)** based on Timer

```
ShaderEffect
{
    property real iGlobalTime: 0
    property real iTimeDeltaSpeed: 0.01    

    Timer
    {
        id: timer
        running: true
        repeat: true
        interval: 10
        onTriggered:
        {
            iGlobalTime += iTimeDeltaSpeed;
        }
    }

    fragmentShader: "
        uniform lowp float iGlobalTime;

        void main()
        {
            // use 'iGlobalTime' in pixel shader...
        }"
}
```

**2)** based on NumberAnimation

```
ShaderEffect
{
    property real iGlobalTime: 0
    property real iTimeDeltaSpeed: 0.01  
    property real iTimeGear: 0  

    NumberAnimation on iTimeGear 
    { 
       loops: Animation.Infinite; 
       from: 0; to: 1; 
       duration: 1000 
     }

    // Whenever chenged 'iTimeGear' we increase global time counter.
    onITimeGearChanged:
    {
        iGlobalTime += iTimeDeltaSpeed;
    }

    fragmentShader: "
        uniform lowp float iGlobalTime;

        void main()
        {
            // use 'iGlobalTime' in pixel shader...
        }"
}
```

I think method with 'Timer' have more performance than with 'NumberAnimation' because 'Timer' change only one property.

But for shaders I want use like "UniformAnimator" or something specialized for ShaderEffects, which have best efficiency, any suggestion?

Comment: In my experience, Timer would be more performant if you want to change variable in some times per second (for example change using interval 100). But if you want to change `time` variable smoothly (in every frame), NumberAnimation is more performant. If you looking for particle system, so there is some internal attributes (`qt_Timestamp`).

Comment: shadertoy in QML was my idea!